# pl pgsql move with variable value

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function that implements pagination using cursors. Function accept parameters `i_limit` and `i_offset`.

```
begin
  -- Search resources.
  select into found_keys trgm_search_resources(i_search_query);
  -- Open cursor
  open master_event_curs(found_keys);
  -- Reposition cursor if the @i_offset is specified
  -- TODO: Replace 5 with variable
  move forward i_offset in master_event_curs;

  -- Limit number of retrieved items
  loop
    exit when i >= i_limit;
    -- Fetch data to the record
    fetch master_event_curs into recordvar;
    exit when not found;
    i = i + 1;

    -- Return master event info.
    return next (select get_master_event_info(recordvar."master_event_uid" :: bigint, i_return_langs));
  end loop;
  -- Return info of found master events.
  return;
end;
```

When I use `move forward 5 in master_event_curs` and everything works fine, but when I try to replace 5 with dynamic `i_offset` variable, the SQL shows syntax error `{char} unexpected`.

I tried to use explicit casting, execute this command using `execute` statement but nothing works.

Could someone give me a hint how  to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [execute format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
execute format('move forward %s in master_event_curs', i_offset);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

What is version of your Postgres? Modern PostgreSQL allows any expression there:

```
do $$
  declare s cursor for select * from pg_class;
  r record;
  i_offset int default 5; 
begin
  open s;
  move forward i_offset in s;
  fetch s into r;
  raise notice '%', r;
  close s;
end;
$$;

NOTICE: (pg_toast_2609,99,11585,0,10,0,2834,0,0,0,0,0,t,f,p,t,3,0,f,f,f,f,f,f,t,n,f,0,561,1,,,)
```

Maybe you are using too old version of PostgreSQL, or maybe there was some any different issue, but `MOVE`, `FETCH` commands supports expressions, so there is not necessary to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: So [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html) is imprecise: *count is a possibly-signed integer constant (...)*

Comment: @klin, probably it is obsolete - I checked source code, and any expression is allowed there.

Comment: Yes, it works well with expressions, the description is outdated.

Comment: @PaveLStehule I'm using the latest stable version of PostgreSQL (PostgreSQL 10.4). Most likely that there is a problem with the DataGrip IDE from JetBrains I'm using for development.

Comment: @KonstantinChsherbakov - maybe - `{char} unexpected` message doesn't look like PostgreSQL's message.

Comment: @klin - I checked documentation, and it is ok. There is two implementations of `FETCH`/`MOVE` commands - SQL and PL/pgSQL. PL/pgSQL allows parametrization, SQL surely not. Although the syntax is almost same, the implementation is little bit different.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find any mention of this in [Using Cursors (in PL/pgSQL)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING) On the contrary, there is the explicit reference to the SQL `FETCH` command: *The direction clause can be any of the variants allowed in the SQL FETCH command (...).*

Comment: @klin - I agree, this is not explicitly described. On other hand - usually you can use variables (any expression) everywhere where expression is not used as SQL identifier. So the described state is not against expected behave. It can be formulated better - currently I have not any idea how.

Comment: Now a novice has no chance to get to such information. I think that one could add a general description of the use of expressions in SQL constructs with appropriate examples in the chapter [PL/pgSQL Under the Hood](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html)

Comment: @klin - it is fixed in documentation now https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=632b4ae92dc6fb92149e94290760b50744e0bd35